# Use conftest.py fixtures in non-test function

Tags: python, pytest, fixtures, conftest

Below is the **Server.py** file

```
class Server():
    def __init__(self, certral=None, user=None, password=None):
        cwd = os.path.dirname(__file__)
        self.propPath = cwd + "/../server-profiles.json"
        print(os.path.normpath(self.propPath))
        with open(os.path.normpath(self.propPath)) as data_file:
            data = json.load(data_file)

    self.propertyDataJson = data
        self.testcategory = data['generic']['category']
```

Below is the **conftest.py** file.

```
def pytest_addoption(parser):
    parser.addoption(
        "--stack", action="store", default="sanity", help="my option: sanity or qa"
    )


@pytest.fixture
def cmdopt(request):
    return request.config.getoption("--stack")
```

Now, I want the user to give input **pytest xyz.py --stack=sanity** and the value should be stored in ***self.testcategory***, for ex: **self.testcategory = sanity** or **self.testcategory = qa** under **Server() class in Server.py** file.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are trying to accomplish with this but if I have to guess:

I think this can only be done if you create a server fixture:

```
@pytest.fixture
def server(cmdopt):
    server_ = Server()
    server_.testcategory = cmdopt
    yield server_
```

Or if that is not an option for you just add the flag in the test function.